# Mongoose MissingSchemaError while loading node.js server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm writing some node.js/express app and i get this message :

> throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
>
> > MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "./models/User".

I generated my project using **express-generator** and my project tree looks like that:

> app.js
>
> bin/
>
> node_modules/
>
> package.json
>
> public/
>
> routes/
>
> views/
>
> models/

I've created four models in **models/** folder:
**user.js**

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var UserSchema = new Schema({
        email: String,
        hash: String,
        salt: String,
        first_name: String,
        last_name: String,
        position: String
    });
    module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**payment.js**

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    require('./user');

    var PaymentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        bookedDate: Date,
        salary: {type: Number, default: 0},
        employee: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
    });
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Payment', PaymentSchema);
```

**task.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('./user');

var TaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    job: String,
    employee: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    estimatedTime: { type: Number, default:0 },
    hoursLogged: { type: Number, default:0 }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', TaskSchema);
```

**vacation.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('./user');
var VacationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    startDate: Date,
    endDate: Date,
    title: String,
    employee: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Vacation', VacationSchema);
```

My error appears at file :**routes\index.js** which starts with loading models:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('../models/user');
require('../models/task');
require('../models/payment');
require('../models/vacation');

var User = mongoose.model('./models/User'); // <-- error throws here
var Task = mongoose.model('./models/Task');
var Vacation = mongoose.model('./models/Vacation');
var Payment = mongoose.model('./models/Payment');
```

But my first file which i load is **app.js**  which starts with:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('./models/user');
require('./models/task');
require('./models/payment');
require('./models/vacation');

var routes = require('./routes/index'); //<-- index.js with error loads here
var users = require('./routes/users');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/local_test');
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: where's the rest of  user.js? All you have is `module.exports = mongoose.model('User', ` .

Comment: mongoose.model('User', UserSchema); I filled it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('../models/user');
require('../models/task');
require('../models/payment');
require('../models/vacation');

var User = mongoose.model('./models/User'); // <-- error throws here
var Task = mongoose.model('./models/Task');
var Vacation = mongoose.model('./models/Vacation');
var Payment = mongoose.model('./models/Payment');
```

to

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var User = require('../models/user');
var Task = require('../models/task');
var Vacation = require('../models/payment');
var Payment = require('../models/vacation');
```

Comment: Sorry, i should post it before: but when i do this i cannot call **find()** function on **Task** object on my route. And i also cannot access any function like **findById** which are accessible in mongoose models.
Example:


    router.get('/tasks', function(req,res,next){
        Task.find(function(err, tasks){
        if(err){ return next(err); }
        res.json(tasks);
    }

Comment: @qwertyxop that sounds like a different issue. Is this in the routes/index.js file or something else?

Comment: Yes it is in my routes/index.js file but i consider to add some more routes in future so this issue will become pretty irritating. Can you please give me some advice about it?